# Current density from overpotential

Tags: electrochemistry, density

> A current of $190$ mA is measure for a $2.5$ cm$^2$ electrode in contact with a solution containing  M$^{2+}$/M$^{3+}$ metal ions at room temperature at a overpotential of +$180$mV. The transfer coefficient is $0.41$.
>
> Determine:
>
> $1$. The exchange current density for the electrode
>
> $2$.
> The current density if the overpotential is +$240$ mV and +$50$mV

I know how to solve the first part of the problem, for which I get:
$$ j_0 = 1.22  mA/cm^2$$

But I don't understand how to solve the second part. How can I calculate the current density from the overpotential if I don't have the exchange current density j$_0$? Or can I use the exchange current density from the first part? I would assume that it can't be used since the overpotential changes but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: I think the ECD is inherent to the charge transfer reaction, doesn't depend on overpotential.

Comment: @MarkWolfman Rather, the OP value depends kind of reciprocally on the ECD value, right ?

Comment: I suppose so. The net current depends on the exchange current combined with the overpotential.